# Datatables: how to create a complex header when initializing with JS

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to create a table with Datatables that has a complex header like the example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/rowspan.html). However, the example from Datatables is using the HTML to define the header. I am create the datatable using an AEM component I built that only allows for JavaScript initialization and defining the columns in the JS not the HTML

For example:

```
"columns": [
    { "title": "&nbsp;", "className": "all" },
    { "title": "Cyclosporin", "className": "all" },
    { "title": "Tacrolimus", "className": "desktop tablet-l" },
    { "title": "Everolimus.", "className": "desktop tablet-l" },
    { "title": "Sirolimus", "className": "desktop tablet-l" },
]
```

Is there any way to create a complex header using js to define the columns or do I have to edit the component to allow for the creation of the header in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think you have to edit the component. Just write a function to add headers with **rowspan** and **colspan** attributes and call it before initialising  the DataTable() on your Table.

As the documentation says [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html), DataTables fully supports colspan and rowspan in the table's header. Not sure, if I understand your question correctly, but if its about just adding headers, then I hope it helps you